# Shared memory error - cannot map an existing or recently created shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, posix, shared-memory

I'm implementing a shared memory to do IPC between 2 processes in Linux Ubuntu.

The idea is to try to get to an existing shared memory. If not found, create it.

After that, adjust the shared memory to its desired size and then map it for usage.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstring>

#define SHARED_MEMORY_KEY "/mysharedmemory"

typedef struct
{
    int code;
    char buffer[500];
} shared_data_t;

shared_data_t *shared_mem_ptr;

void init_shared_memory()
{
    // Open shared memory
    int shmid = shm_open(SHARED_MEMORY_KEY, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);

    std::cout << "OPEN: " << shmid << std::endl;

    if (shmid < 0)
    {
        std::cout  << "Not found... creating..." << std::endl;

        key_t key = ftok(SHARED_MEMORY_KEY, 1);

        // Does not exist - create it
        shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(shared_data_t), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);

        if (shmid == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Fatal error creating shared memory." << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    int rc = ftruncate(shmid, sizeof(shared_data_t));

    if (rc == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Fatal error resizing shared memory." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Attach data struct to the segment to get a pointer to it.
    shared_mem_ptr = (shared_data_t *) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

    if (shared_mem_ptr == (void *)-1)
    {
        std::cout << "Fatal error mapping shared memory." << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

On every run I'm getting the following error:

```
Fatal error mappeing shared memory
```

So, `shmat` is failing on every call and no idea of what is causing this problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When getting an error from a system call, your first action must be to get the error code in the variable "errno" and maybe print the result of perror(), in order to know the exact cause of error.

Comment: That message can't be coming from the code you posted. It has a typo in `mappeing` that isn't in the code.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need to use `typedef` for struct types. The struct name automatically becomes a type name.

Comment: For C++ I would use boost.interprocess. being able to share strings and vectors using the shared allocator, makes everything much smoother than dealing with raw pointers again: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html